# How to make business logic code maintainable when working with multiple states?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am developing a UI Application for a very simple phone app, the UI is based entirely on the state of Call in a container provided to me by a third party library.

Below is a sample Call object that I am working with;

```
public class Call {
    private boolean isTannoyCall;
    private long callStart;
    private int callId;
    private int callState;
    private CallDirection mCallDirection = CallDirection.OUTGOING;
    private int mediaStatus;
    private boolean mediaHasVideoStream;
    private long connectStart;
        private int lastStatusCode;
        private boolean callIsMuted;
        private boolean callIsInConference;

    //removed getters and setters
}
```

A populated call object is then passed around my application, in various places I have to carry out business logic to check if I should be carrying out an action etc. Below is an example of an event listener method for new calls within the app.

```
public void update() {
    int activeCallCount = 0;
    int incomingCallCount = 0;

    for (Call call : container.getCalls()) {

        boolean isIncomingDirection = call.getCallDirection() == CallDirection.INCOMING;

        boolean isIncomingCall = isIncomingDirection
                && call.getCallState() == CallState.INCOMING && !call.isTannoyCall();

        boolean isActiveCall = call.isActive()
                && call.getCallState() != call.InvState.INCOMING && !call.isTannoyCall();

        if (isIncomingCall) {
            incomingCallCount++;
        } else if (isActiveCall) {
            activeCallCount++;
        }

        boolean isMissedCall = isIncomingDirection
                && call.getCallState() == call.InvState.DISCONNECTED
                && call.getCallStart() == 0
                && !call.isTannoyCall();

        if (isMissedCall) {
            missedCallManager.increment();
        }
    }
    incomingCallUpdate(incomingCallCount);
    activeCallUpdate(activeCallCount);
}
```

In areas of the application where I need to do a lot of boolean based checks, like sample 1. How can I do this whilst keeping the code maintainable?  As every time I need to add a new condition (e.g. the latest "don't update if tannoy call"), I have to modify the appropriate `if` statements.

Comment: Minor issues in your post that you could fix : I would add the language to your question and there is one code block that is missing a bracket in the formatted block. Except for that excellent question!

Comment: Thanks, I originally avoided the language tag as I was hoping to attract answers from users with various programming styles :)

Comment: In my experience, people here don't limit themselves to one language and answer if they have something to say!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems [data](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DataEnvy)/[feature](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FeatureEnvySmell) envy. Move the boolean conditions to the `Call` object:

```
public class Call {
    ...

    public boolean isIncomingDirection()
        return callDirection == CallDirection.INCOMING;
    }

    public boolean isIncomingCall() {
        return isIncomingDirection()
            && callState == CallState.INCOMING && !isTannoyCall;
    }

    public boolean isActiveCall() {
        return isActive()
                && callState != InvState.INCOMING && !isTannoyCall;
    }

    public boolean isMissedCall() {
        return isIncomingDirection()
                && callState == InvState.DISCONNECTED
                && callStart == 0
                && !isTannoyCall;
    }       
}
```

See also: *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G14: Feature Envy*

Comment: One of the best books I've ever read! Get that book, read it, and then read it again!

Comment: This really helps with the first sample.